# How do I change the connection character set when using ODBC to connect to MS Access?

Tags: php, sql, ms-access, unicode, odbc

This is how i connect with database:

```
$dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\bd\\db\\icr.accdb;Uid=Admin");
```

In my database I have data and fields with polish characters, so sql query works only when file is encoded in ANSI. But my whole website have charset utf8 (also have lots of polish characters). So, there is any possible way to change charset of database to utf8?

I was trying this:

```
$dbh->exec("set names utf8");
```

and this:

```
$dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\bd\\db\\icr.accdb;Uid=Admin", null, null, array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
  ));
```

but both didn't work. Any ideas?

//don't ask me why I use access database with php -> i have to use it in my university project :/

edit:
code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<body>
<?php
try{
   // Connect
   $dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\bd\\db\\icr.accdb;Uid=Admin");
        $dbh->exec("set names utf8");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Miasta";
                        $myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
        {
echo $row['Nazwa'] .' - '. $row['IDWojewództwa'] . '<br />';
$stringData = $row['Nazwa'] .' - '. $row['IDWojewództwa'] . '<br />';
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
        }
fclose($fh);
    /*** close the database connection ***/
    $dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While `SET NAMES` tends to be cross-platform, the `MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` attribute is MySQL-only.  What, *exactly* happens when you issue `SET NAMES utf8`?  Saying it's "not working" does not help us.

Comment: If I'm not wrong access database use utf-8 since like 2000 version. Did you tried to select some rows with polish characters and write them to file and open them in text editor with utf-8 encoding?

Comment: @piotrekkr - yeah you have right, file have right polish characters, here is my code sample: http://pastebin.com/xiJSPRj6 , and now, if file is encoded in ANSI, there are missing polish characters, when i change encoding to UTF8 i get that error: Notice: Undefined index: IDWojewództwa in C:\xampp\htdocs\bd\conn.php on line 14
Wroc�aw - 

Notice: Undefined index: IDWojewództwa in C:\xampp\htdocs\bd\conn.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined index: IDWojewództwa in C:\xampp\htdocs\bd\conn.php on line 14
Warszawa - 

Notice: Undefined index: IDWojewództwa in

Comment: You want to use incorrect index from `$row` array. Change this `echo $row['Nazwa']...` to `echo '<pre>'; var_dump($row); echo '</pre>'` you will see what indexes and values are returned from database for each row. Use those from `var_dump()`;

Comment: @piotrekkr here is result (file have utf8 encoding) http://i.imgur.com/IP2Vh.png

Comment: I'm not quite sure that it is utf-8 can you save page source but using `Save as` not copying to editor.

Comment: Second thing attach your code to question it's easier that way.

Comment: In Notepad++ you can easily change encoding :)

Answer (score 1):

solution:

```
$tresc1 .= iconv("iso-8859-2","utf-8", $row['Nazwa'] .' - '. $row['IDWojewodztwa'] . '<br />');
```

Comment: this fix doesn't work for me, my problem is the same, Access file with polish characters imported the same way. Is this all you changed to your code? nothing else?

Answer (score 0):

Use as follows:

```
$dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb  *.accdb)};Dbq=path\;Uid=Admin");
$dbh->exec("set names utf8");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can refer following link. this may help you.>>http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/connector-odbc-configuration-connection-parameters.html

Also Find>>http://www.herongyang.com/JDBC/JDBC-ODBC-MS-Access-Connection.html For more programs